# Talegram bot: как отправить фото всем пользователям бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Как отправить фото всем пользователям бота? Например: любой пользователь шлет боту любое фото, а бот шлет это фото всем пользователям данного бота?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в базе данных таблицу всех пользователей, пользующихся ботом (Когда пользователь отправляет боту "/start" - нужно создать запись в БД с его ID (`message.chat.id`)). Потом, для каждого такого пользователя отправляйте сообщения.

Comment: Это понятно, но как принять фото от пользователя, чтобы после послать всем?
Когда пользователь шлет фото, куда оно сохраняется?
Судя по всему фото должно храниться у меня на диске, что бы его после открыть:`files = {'photo': open('foto.jpg', 'rb')}`, куда и как оно сохраняется?

Comment: Фото хранится на сервере телеграма. Чтобы его загрузить: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912852/download-image-python-telegram-api . Также, вместо того, чтобы загружать фото, а потом отсылать его куче пользователей отдельно, эффективнее будет его просто переслать (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046038/9158268)